# How do I use Scss files in CodeSandbox?

Tags: css, sass, codesandbox

I haven't used SASS or SCSS in anything besides codepen before so apologies if this is a basic question, but my CSS was working fine, but I wanted to nest some tags, and when I setup the SCSS and SASS dependencies and changed my filename to .scss, all of my formatting went away. I read something somewhere about importing an scss file into the css file, but I'm not really sure how to accomplish that.

Here's a link to the code sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/oj15rk1vw9

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use the Parcel Bundler template instead of the create-react-app template

[image]

Also if you're using react add `react` and `react-dom` as dependencies since the Parcel Bundler template only comes with parcel as a dev dependency

https://codesandbox.io/s/q7877ov756

Comment: Is there a way to change the template without having to create a whole new sandbox and copy everything over?

Comment: I don't know sorry, I know that you can import a project from [Github](https://codesandbox.io/s/github) or with the [cli](https://codesandbox.io/s/cli)

Comment: I just tried a parcel and copying everything over, and now nothing is displaying at all. Care to look? https://codesandbox.io/s/rw0j2orqmp

Comment: Just figured it out. It was because I wasn't setting the script in the index. What's the difference between parcel and react templates such that index.html can't be in a public folder and has to explicitly indicate script source in the index.html?

Answer (score 8):

If you just change all instances of `style.css` to `style.scss` then it'll work

Comment: You have to make sure `node-sass` package is installed. [See docs](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-a-sass-stylesheet/).

Comment: Also required for me was making sure I had the sandbox template set to `react` and adding these lines to my package.json under the `scripts` group
`"build:css": "node-sass src/ -o src/ ",`
`"watch:css": "npm run build:css && node-sass src/ -o src/ -w -r"`